# How to unit test grails service method which uses mongo query?

Tags: mongodb, unit-testing, grails

I have a service with a method called getEmployeeSalary that i want to unit test but i can not mock and query the employee collections

```
private List getEmployeeSalary(String department, Date from){

     def db = grailsApplication.mainContext.mongo.getDB(grailsApplication.config.grails.mongo.databaseName)

     List employeeSalaryByDepartment = db.employee.aggregate([
                [ '$match' : [ department: department, 
                  dateCreated: ['$gte': from] ] ],
                [
                   $group' : [
                            '_id': "\$department",
                             'sum': [ '$sum': "\$salary" ]
                            ]
                ]
        ]).results()*.values()

   return employeeSalaryByDepartment
}
```

Comment: My Grails and Groovy is a bit rusty, but  iirc the way you have done it, you need to mock `grailsApplication.mainContext.mongo.getDB` to return another mock object  for `db` which mocks `employee.aggregate` to return  the various results you want to test.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I tried to mock it on my unit test setup method by doing grailsApplication.mainContext.mongo.demand.getDB(0..1) {return []} but i am getting java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'demand' on null object

Comment: If you want to test criteria, so it will be greater to do it in Integration test. if no, try to replace this criteria to method and mock it using metaClass